# How to reproduce the plot in this manner as in image

Tags: python, r

I am looking for reproducing my plots as indicated in image.

[image]

Practically i have three files in .bed version that shows enrichment of peaks.
Now i wish to plot these.
I need help with identifying a package that could help me to explore this appearance
I hope i am clear, but if not i may be able to explain further.

While what i have tried is R package KaryoplotR but its just different.

Comment: Unfortunately, asking for software library or package recommendations is off-topic for this forum, and it's unlikely that someone will create this figure for you entirely without any data or effort. You may find better luck elsewhere, or reaching out to authors who have produced similar plots. Good luck!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.